# FreeDOS not working, kinda?

Tags: ms-dos, freedos

I am trying to make a usb bootable with rufus to run freeDOS, however, it may turn on, but then I cannot type anything. I also tried with the original DOS image with rufus and still, nothing worked. any help?
Btw, I am French and I noticed it saying that it used a certain layout when booting so it might be linked to this but I legit have no idea. Thank you!

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/1688959/clarification-on-using-rufus-to-create-a-bootable-live-freedos-usb-drive

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.